# Hi folks, Can someone help me with thymeleaf, how to get multiple object(say Address Object)?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

I am using springboot 2.6.0 version, thymeleaf framework as view template and Spring MVC pattern.

I have Profile object -> profile has list of address .I am confused how to get multiple address object from thymeleaf template.

can someone help?
Below is code snippet:

```
public class DoctorProfileModel {

    private String email;

    private String dateOfBirth;

    private String gender;

    private String dateOfJoining;

    private String specialization;

    private List<QualificationModel> qualification;

    private List<AddressModel> addresses;

    private String phoneNumber;

    //getter and Setters


}
```

I want to bind one of my html page for updating the profile's address and qualification.

I am getting confused what to do?

Comment: You should provide a bit more information including some code snippets and such. I'd suggest you to read through the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet - I have edited the post and add my model class